# Como hacer detección de objetos con deep-learning e imagenes satelitales?

Tags: python, machine-learning

Gente, tengo un desafío en el trabajo:
Una empresa X que vende tecnología para la purificación de gas, quiere saber dónde existen productores de biogás en todo el país, con el objetivo de localizar lugares donde pueda vender su tecnología y determinar si existe tal demanda.

- El primer problema es que no existe una base de datos que contenga registros de productores de biogás.
- La solución que se me ocurrió fue implementar un modelo de aprendizaje profundo (deep learning) para localizar plantas de biogás mediante imágenes satelitales.
  Las plantas de biogás vistas desde arriba tienen un patrón muy similar al de la imagen de abajo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

*(Aunque pueden confundirse con otras plantas o industrias con infraestructuras similares)*

1. ¿Alguien podría darme orientación sobre si es posible realizar este tipo de trabajo? Tengo experiencia en ciencia de datos y Python avanzado, aunque nunca he trabajado con deep learning.
2. También pensé en utilizar Google Earth Engine con deep learning, aunque no entiendo bien si realmente sería el enfoque correcto. ¿Qué otras herramientas necesitaría utilizar para obtener los resultados? Solo necesito un paso a paso de cómo hacerlo y si es posible.

Observación: Necesito aplicar un barrido en imagenes satelitales de un pais entero

Desde ya agradezco la ayuda

Comment: No se de que país eres, pero se me hace difícil pensar que no exista una lista de aquellas industrias, y si no estuviera publicada siempre se pueden solicitar.

Comment: Efectivamente, me parece muy raro que el ministerio de industria de tu pais no pueda conseguir una lista de ese tipo de empresas... habéis probado a proceder por la via pública solicitando el listado? Seguramente haya que pagarlo, pero es imposible que no exista algún tipo de listado de eso... Una simple búsqueda en google me ha permitido ver listados con el nº de plantas de biogás por país/ciudad de todo europa. Quien haya hecho esa lista imagino que tendrá acceso a algo más que fotos de satélite y python! Me parece que intentas matar moscas a cañonazos, no todas las tareas necesitan IA :)

Comment: Hola! tiene sentido lo que dicen. Claramente ya pensé en esas opciones, vivo en un país de AL, donde las regulaciones y licenciamiento de plantas no dependen necesariamente del sector Federal, sino que cada municipio tiene o estado tiene el registro de licencias. Por lo tanto debería entrar en las plataforma de cada municipio o estado, es un trabajo de hormiga muy ineficiente. El problema también, es que, los registros que existen están desactualizados. Por lo tanto no me soluciona el problema.